# Is there a way to mark files in iOS so they are not purged from Library/Caches directory in low storage situation

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems

We have an app developed with a Newsstand kit, so files are stored inside of Library/Caches and we can't change the location because of the use of Newsstand. And we want those files not to get purged  in low storage situation. So we mark all of them with "do not back up" attribute according to iOS Data Storage Guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

"4. Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations."

But unfortunately all of them get purged anyway (we tested it in iOS 11.3-12.0). Can we, please, use some other methods to disable purging?
Any other ideas to make it work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't stop all your back issues from being purged in a low storage situation.

Newsstand Kit allows you to specify the issue that the user is currently reading, by setting the `currentlyReadingIssue` property of `NKLibrary`.

According to the docs: "Newsstand Kit takes this setting into consideration when it purges back issues because of low levels of available flash storage."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/newsstandkit/nklibrary/1615812-currentlyreadingissue?language=objc

There's no way to force NewsstandKit to keep *all* back issues in a low storage situation.

See the Newsstand FAQ, in particular "Will all of my issues be automatically stored on the user's device, indefinitely?":

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2280/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011215-CH1-MANAGING_CONTENT-CAN_I_MOVE_MY_ISSUES_OUT_OF_THE_DEFAULT_NEWSSTAND_STORAGE_LOCATION_ONCE_THEY_RE_DOWNLOADED__OR_DOWNLOAD_ISSUES_TO_ANOTHER_LOCATION_

> "Newsstand Kit provides a managed repository for your issues located
>   at the contentURL for the NKIssue. This managed repository acts as a
>   cache for the content you host on your servers, and like any cache is
>   susceptible to eviction as system resources become low.
>
> In such an event, the information you provide Newsstand Kit via the
>   currentlyReadingIssue property and the date parameter in
>   addIssueWithName:date: helps Newsstand Kit to prioritize which content
>   is most critical for the user as it evicts elements from the cache.
>   Your Newsstand app should be capable of re-downloading back issues at
>   the user's request, should such resource constraints arise."

Newsstand Kit prioritizes which issues it keeps in a low storage situation and, unfortunately, you can't have any influence over that outside of keeping the `currentlyReadingIssue` property up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you, Pete. According to our observations it's most probably iOS purges everything from Library/Caches. The last app we added from app store to iPad could not be installed due to a low space and with every new attempt our app's icon is flashing once and Library/Caches is empty. As we can't find any solution to this we are now replacing Newsstand Kit functionality and moving all the issues and the database to <Application_Home>/Documents folder, so it couldn't be purged, thanks.